# not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin on jQuery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, load, click

I try work this code but not working.

```
$(".edit").click(function(){
$(".edit").load("another.html #user_adr");
})
```

When i check via Firebug, get this error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load file://localhost/Users/Desktop/site-new/another.html. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

How can i fix it?

Comment: `another.html #user_adr` is not a valid URL

Comment: @dakait - It is valid. jQuery strips out everything following the space. See [the docs](http://api.jquery.com/load/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Browsers have recently started treating calls to other files on the local file system as cross domain requests. Calling pages from other domains is banned by default security settings, and that's what you're running into.

Your best bet is to use a simple web server on your local machine to serve your pages instead.

Answer (score 0):

No. you are performing cross-domain request . you cant do cross domain request without proper access mechanism.  [Cross Orgin Resource sharing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing)

1. You need a webserver to serve the request. you cannot load the file from file protocol.
2. browers don't allow file:/// protocol for AJAX calls for security reasons.

Comment: again thank you. How can i add fadeIn effect on this function?